# Speed of Convergence in Different Situations

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there is some method in math to measure the speed of convergence.

For example, suppose we have a Normal Distribution with parameters $\mu$ = 5 and $\sigma$ =5. Suppose we generate some random data of size $n$ from this distributions in 3 different approaches and estimate $\hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\sigma}$ based on the random samples:

- 1st Approach (Single Sample): parameter estimation based on a single sample of size $n$
- 2nd Approach (Bootstrap): parameter estimation using $n$ bootstrap samples from a single sample of size $n$
- 3rd Approach (Multi-sample): parameter estimation using $n$ independent samples each of size $n$

My guess is that the 3rd way will be the "best" (i.e. smallest volatility, closest to real values with smaller sample sizes) since you are exposed to more variability.

I wrote some R code to illustrate this idea over different sample sizes:

```
library(ggplot2)


# Initialize vectors 
mean_vec <- numeric(1000)
var_vec <- numeric(1000)
boot_mean_vec <- numeric(1000)
boot_var_vec <- numeric(1000)
multi_sample_mean_vec <- numeric(1000)
multi_sample_var_vec <- numeric(1000)

# Simulate data and calculate statistics
for (n in 1:1000) {
    data <- rnorm(n, 5, 5)
    mean_vec[n] <- mean(data)
    var_vec[n] <- var(data)
    
    # Bootstrap
    bootstrap_mean <- bootstrap_var <- numeric(1000)
    for (i in 1:1000) {
        bootstrap_sample <- sample(data, n, replace = TRUE)
        bootstrap_mean[i] <- mean(bootstrap_sample)
        bootstrap_var[i] <- var(bootstrap_sample)
    }
    boot_mean_vec[n] <- mean(bootstrap_mean)
    boot_var_vec[n] <- mean(bootstrap_var)
    
    # Multiple independent samples
    multi_sample_mean <- multi_sample_var <- numeric(n)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        multi_sample_data <- rnorm(n, 5, 5)
        multi_sample_mean[i] <- mean(multi_sample_data)
        multi_sample_var[i] <- var(multi_sample_data)
    }
    multi_sample_mean_vec[n] <- mean(multi_sample_mean)
    multi_sample_var_vec[n] <- mean(multi_sample_var)
}

# Create data frames 
df_mean <- data.frame(n = 1:1000, Mean = mean_vec, BootstrapMean = boot_mean_vec, MultiSampleMean = multi_sample_mean_vec)
df_var <- data.frame(n = 1:1000, Variance = var_vec, BootstrapVariance = boot_var_vec, MultiSampleVariance = multi_sample_var_vec)

#plots
p1 <- ggplot(df_mean, aes(n)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Mean, color = "Mean calculated on single sample of size n"), size = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = BootstrapMean, color = "Mean calculated on n bootstrap samples of size n"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(aes(y = MultiSampleMean, color = "Mean calculated on n independent samples of size n"), size = 1, linetype = "dotdash") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype = "dotted", color = "black") +
    labs(title = "Mean vs. Bootstrap Mean vs. Multi-Sample Mean", x = "n", y = "Value") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Mean calculated on single sample of size n" = "blue", "Mean calculated on n bootstrap samples of size n" = "red", "Mean calculated on n independent samples of size n" = "green")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(df_var, aes(n)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Variance, color = "Variance calculated on single sample of size n"), size = 1) +
    geom_line(aes(y = BootstrapVariance, color = "Variance calculated on n bootstrap samples of size n"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(aes(y = MultiSampleVariance, color = "Variance calculated on n independent samples of size n"), size = 1, linetype = "dotdash") +
    labs(title = "Variance vs. Bootstrap Variance vs. Multi-Sample Variance", x = "n", y = "Value") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Variance calculated on single sample of size n" = "blue", "Variance calculated on n bootstrap samples of size n" = "red", "Variance calculated on n independent samples of size n" = "green")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Based on these simulations, we can see that all approaches eventually converge to their true values as the sample size increases, but Approach 3 seems to fluctuate less and achieve this faster compared to Approach 1 and Approach 2.

**My Question:** Mathematically, I think has to do with the Law of Large Numbers - but is there something we can mathematically do to describe the "speed of convergence"?

Thanks!